# Adding the ball of foot to a rig

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm following a tutorial: [link](https://youtu.be/WpgDjKIxYOA?t=892), using Blender 2.79, but in my rig I don't have the ball of foot.

Since my purpose is to move the body delicately, I wonder if adding a bone for the ball of foot is necessary.

How can I add a ball of foot to my rig?

[image]
[image]

Comment: PS I believe that part is called heel, while the ball is the region in front, just before the toe. I'm not a native speaker though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to Edit Mode, right click on the big ball under the ankle, press `E` and make another bone.

[image]

[image]